# yaml syntax error when defining variables using WHEN

Tags: yaml, ansible

I defined these in defaults/main.yml:

```
- mode : production

- consul_server_address :192.168.1.5
  when : mode == "production"

- consul_server_address :192.168.2.5
  when : mode == "staging"
```

but I got:

```
The offending line appears to be:

- consul_server_address : 192.168.1.5
  when : mode == "production"
       ^ here
```

When I add a space after colons on `consul_server_address`, the error changes to:

```
ERROR! The default/main.yml file for role 'dnsmasq' must contain a dictionary of 
variables
```

I spent some time on yaml syntax but I think this idea is wrong and I should do using another ansible-playbook solution.

Comment: This is not valid YAML input, and the corresponding error is not a YAML error but an ansible error. I assume you provide us with something else than the actual input data, because with this you get a different error.

Comment: You're right. I skipped heading lines. I usually start defaults/main.yml with : --- (\n\n) variable : value . I used such a thing for this file but I got error and tried to edit it. This is the final version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on Ansible's IRC channel suggested me to use `groupvars/hostvars` for this purpose.

I edited my `hosts` inventory file and did something like this:

```
[nginx-staging]
IP_ADDRESS OR FQDN  

[nginx-staging:vars]
...
consul_server_address=192.168.2.5


[nginx-production]
IP_ADDRESS OR FQDN

[nginx-production:vars]
...
consul_server_address=192.168.1.5
```

and it worked for me with a simpler and more straight forward solution.

Answer (score 1):

You start your YAML with:

```
- mode : production
```

`-` denotes a sequence item, so this line defines that the root element of your YAML document is a sequence. Another sequence item follows:

```
- consul_server_address : 192.168.1.5
```

But now, there is a line which is *not* a sequence item:

```
when : mode == "production"
```

This is invalid because we are at indentation level `0`, which contains the root element, which is a sequence, which may only contain sequence items. But `when : …` is a mapping key and therefor illegal here.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
- mode : production

- consul_server_address : 192.168.1.5
  when : mode == "production"

- consul_server_address : 192.168.2.5
  when : mode == "staging"
```

By properly indenting the `when` lines, they are keys of the mapping contained in the sequence item.

Comment: Actually the file is like you wrote. A typo when pasting the file content on the post. Sorry for that. I edited the original post.

Comment: Well then the error is that your root object is a sequence, but a mapping (named *dictionary* in the error message) is expected. I don't know ansible good enough to tell you how to fix that.